# What are the mime types of the various file types native to .NET?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mime-types, content-type

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to open files from a server, by going to File\Open\File (Control-O) and typing in a URL. The server is serving the document from an URL without an extension (http://hostname/path/document).

If I set the mime type to text/xml, Visual Studio properly opens the document as an XML document when using text/xml, and a JavaScript document when using text/javascript. What are the mime types for .vb, .cs and other native file types in .NET? I've tried text/plain, text/csharp, and others, but all attempts opens as plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you serve it with `Content-Disposition: attachment` and make sure the file name has the right extension? (the URL can stay the same...)

Comment: Awesome, that works. I still wonder if there is a mime type for these various file types.

Comment: My guess is no. This stuff usually works by detecting extensions or or maybe parsing the text to see if the IDE can figure out the language. Not through MIME types.

Comment: You can retrieve the registered MIME type from the registry using this: http://www.bytemycode.com/snippets/snippet/918/1/ - the official default MIME type for a C# source file is "text/plain".  You could try registering it as "application/vnd-ms-c-sharp" in the registry - but I imagine that may actually be its official MIME type if MS decides to go that route.